# How to run periodic celery task manually from terminal in pyramid?

Tags: python-2.7, celery, pyramid, ubuntu-10.04

I am working on a 'pyramid(pylon)' project. I have configured celery to run some tasks periodically and it works fine. But I am struggling on how to run any of the task from terminal manually. The directory structure of my project is

```
/pyramid/
    celeryconfig.py
    development.ini
    setup.py
    /views/celerytasks/
        __init.py__
        mytask1.py
        mytask2.py
```

Here 'celeryconfig.py' contains all the settings about celery like 'CELERY_IMPORTS', 'CELERY_QUEUES' and 'CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE'. I have some task in 'mytask1.py' file which used to run once a day. But how can I run it from pshell manually? I am using ubuntu 10.04.

Can anybody tell?

**SOLUTION:**

```
1- Go to the application root folder, in my case '/pyramid/'.
2- Run 'pshell development.ini'
3- >>> from views.celerytasks.mytask1 import CeleryTask1
4- >>> celeryTask1 = CeleryTask1()    // Create instance of imported class
5- >>> celeryTask1.delay()     // Finally here the task will run
```

Comment: Finally I found the solution for it. Just see it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine it should be something like

```
from views.celerytasks.mytask1 import my_mega_task_number_one
my_mega_task_number_one.delay()
```

(a separate worker process needs to be running)

Comment: What you mean by 'separate worker process needs to be running'? Can you please specify it.

Comment: I'm not sure how your system is set up, but with Celery you usually have a process which schedules tasks (your webserver or pshell or a console script), and one or more "worker" processes, potentially running on different machines, which take the scheduled tasks from the queue and actually execute them. Refer to the Celery docs for details.